# How to create a map which onClick opens a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to create a map which on click opens a form, I have created an HTML map and HTML form, The thing I want is when someone clicks on any state of map it opens a pop-up form which I have created, Thankyou in advance

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="pop()">

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <svg xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="us-map" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" sodipodi:docname="Republican_Party_presidential_primaries_results,_2016.svg"
    inkscape:version="0.91 r13725" x="0px" y="0px" width="959px" height="593px" viewBox="174 100 959 593" enable-background="new 174 100 959 593" xml:space="preserve">
<sodipodi:namedview bordercolor="#666666" objecttolerance="10" pagecolor="#ffffff" borderopacity="1" gridtolerance="10" guidetolerance="10" inkscape:cx="509.19152" inkscape:cy="282.2353" inkscape:zoom="1.2137643" showgrid="false" id="namedview71" inkscape:current-layer="g5" inkscape:window-maximized="1" inkscape:window-y="-8" inkscape:window-x="-8" inkscape:pageopacity="0" inkscape:window-height="1017" inkscape:window-width="1920" inkscape:pageshadow="2">
    </sodipodi:namedview>
<g id="g5">
    <path id="HI" data-info="<div>State: Hawaii</div><div>Capital: Honolulu</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M407.1,619.3l1.9-3.6l2.3-0.3l0.3,0.8l-2.1,3.1H407.1z M417.3,615.6l6.1,2.6l2.1-0.3l1.6-3.9   l-0.6-3.4l-4.2-0.5l-4,1.8L417.3,615.6z M448,625.6l3.7,5.5l2.4-0.3l1.1-0.5l1.5,1.3l3.7-0.2l1-1.5l-2.9-1.8l-1.9-3.7l-2.1-3.6   l-5.8,2.9L448,625.6z M468.2,634.5l1.3-1.9l4.7,1l0.6-0.5l6.1,0.6l-0.3,1.3l-2.6,1.5l-4.4-0.3L468.2,634.5z M473.5,639.7l1.9,3.9   l3.1-1.1l0.3-1.6l-1.6-2.1l-3.7-0.3V639.7z M480.5,638.5l2.3-2.9l4.7,2.4l4.4,1.1l4.4,2.7v1.9l-3.6,1.8l-4.8,1l-2.4-1.5   L480.5,638.5z M497.1,654.1l1.6-1.3l3.4,1.6l7.6,3.6l3.4,2.1l1.6,2.4l1.9,4.4l4,2.6l-0.3,1.3l-3.9,3.2l-4.2,1.5l-1.5-0.6l-3.1,1.8   l-2.4,3.2l-2.3,2.9l-1.8-0.2l-3.6-2.6l-0.3-4.5l0.6-2.4l-1.6-5.7l-2.1-1.8l-0.2-2.6l2.3-1l2.1-3.1l0.5-1l-1.6-1.8L497.1,654.1z"/>
   
    <path id="MO" data-info="<div>State: Missouri</div><div>Capital: Jefferson City</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M729.8,349.5l-2.5-3.1l-1.1-2.3l-7.8,0.7l-9.8,0.5l-25.4,0.9l-13.5,0.2l-7.9,0.1l-2.3,0.1l1.3,2.5   l-0.2,2.3l2.5,3.9l3.1,4.1l3.1,2.7l2.3,0.2l1.4,0.9v3l-1.8,1.6l-0.5,2.3l2.1,3.4l2.5,3l2.5,1.8l1.4,11.7l-0.7,35.3l0.2,4.7l0.5,5.4   l23.4-0.1l23.2-0.7l20.8-0.8l11.7-0.2l2.2,3.4l-0.7,3.3l-3.1,2.4l-0.6,1.8l5.4,0.5l3.9-0.7l1.7-5.5l0.7-5.9l2.3-2l1.7-1.5l2.1-1   l0.1-2.9l0.6-1.7l-1-1.7l-2.7,0.1l-2.2-2.6l-1.4-4.2l0.8-2.5l-1.9-3.4l-1.8-4.6l-4.8-0.8l-7-5.6l-1.7-4.1l0.8-3.2l2.1-6.1l0.5-2.9   l-1.9-1l-6.9-0.8l-1-1.7l-0.1-4.2l-5.5-3.4l-7-7.8l-2.3-7.3l-0.2-4.2L729.8,349.5z"/>
    <path id="AR" data-info="<div>State: Arkansas</div><div>Capital: Little Rock</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M765,445l-3.8,0.9l-6.2-0.5l0.7-3l3.2-2.7l0.5-2.3l-1.8-3l-11,0.5l-20.8,0.9l-23.3,0.7L679,437   l1.6,6.9v8.2l1.4,11l0.2,37.8l2.3,1.9l3-1.4l2.7,1.1l0.4,10.3l22.9-0.1l18.9-0.8l10.1-0.2l1.1-2.1l-0.3-3.5l-1.8-3l1.6-1.5   l-1.6-2.5l0.7-2.5l1.4-5.6l2.5-2.1l-0.7-2.3l3.7-5.4l2.7-1.4l-0.1-1.5l-0.3-1.8l2.9-5.6l2.4-1.3l0.4-3.4l1.8-1.2l0.9-4.2l-1.3-4   l4-2.4l0.6-2l1.2-4.3L765,445z"/>
    <path id="OK" data-info="<div>State: Oklahoma</div><div>Capital: Oklahoma City</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M549.3,422.6l-10.7-0.5l-6.4-0.5l0.3,0.2l-0.7,10.4l22,1.4l32.1,1.3l-2.3,24.4l-0.5,17.8l0.2,1.6   l4.3,3.7l2.1,1.1l0.7-0.2l0.7-2.1l1.4,1.8h2.1v-1.4l2.7,1.4l-0.5,3.9l4.1,0.2l2.5,1.1l4.1,0.7l2.5,1.8l2.3-2.1l3.4,0.7l2.5,3.4h0.9   v2.3l2.3,0.7l2.3-2.3l1.8,0.7h2.5l0.9,2.5l4.8,1.8l1.4-0.7l1.8-4.1h1.1l1.1,2.1l4.1,0.7l3.7,1.4l3,0.9l1.8-0.9l0.7-2.5h4.3l2.1,0.9   l2.7-2.1h1.1l0.7,1.6h4.1l1.6-2.1l1.8,0.5l2.1,2.5l3.2,1.8l3.2,0.9l1.9,1.1l-0.4-37.2l-1.4-11l-0.2-8.9l-1.4-6.5l-0.8-7.2l-0.1-3.8   l-12.1,0.3l-46.4-0.5l-45-2.1L549.3,422.6z"/>
    <path id="KS" data-info="<div>State: Kansas</div><div>Capital: Topeka</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M677.4,425.1l-12.6,0.2l-46.1-0.5l-44.6-2.1l-24.6-1.3l4.1-64.7l21.8,0.8l40.5,1.4l44.1,0.5h5.1   l3.2,3.2l2.8,0.2l0.9,1.1v2l-1.8,1.6l-0.5,2.6l2.2,3.6l2.5,3.1l2.5,2l1.1,11.2L677.4,425.1z"/>
    <path id="LA" data-info="<div>State: Louisiana</div><div>Capital: Baton Rouge</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M776.2,573l-1-2.6l-1.1-3.1l-3.3-3.5l0.9-6.8l-0.1-1.1l-1.3,0.3l-8.2,0.9l-25,0.5l-0.7-2.4l0.9-8.5   l3.3-5.9l5-8.7l-0.6-2.4l1.3-0.7l0.5-2l-2.3-2.1l-0.1-1.9l-1.8-4.3l-0.5-5.9l-9.7,0.1l-19.2,0.9l-22.2,0l0,9.6l0.7,9.4l0.7,3.9   l2.5,4.1l0.9,5l4.3,5.5l0.2,3.2l0.7,0.7l-0.7,8.5l-3,5l1.6,2.1l-0.7,2.5l-0.7,7.3l-1.4,3.2l0.1,3.6l4.7-1.5l8.1-0.3l10.3,3.6   l6.5,1.1l3.7-1.5l3.2,1.1l3.2,1l0.8-2.1l-3.2-1.1l-2.6,0.5l-2.7-1.6c0,0,0.2-1.3,0.8-1.5c0.6-0.2,3.1-1,3.1-1l1.8,1.5l1.8-1   l3.2,0.6l1.5,2.4l0.3,2.3l4.5,0.3l1.8,1.8l-0.8,1.6l-1.3,0.8l1.6,1.6l8.4,3.6l3.6-1.3l1-2.4l2.6-0.6l1.8-1.5l1.3,1l0.8,2.9   l-2.3,0.8l0.6,0.6l3.4-1.3l2.3-3.4l0.8-0.5l-2.1-0.3l0.8-1.6l-0.2-1.5l2.1-0.5l1.1-1.3l0.6,0.8c0,0-0.2,3.1,0.6,3.1   c0.8,0,4.2,0.6,4.2,0.6l4,1.9l1,1.5h2.9l1.1,1l2.3-3.1v-1.5h-1.3l-3.4-2.7l-5.8-0.8l-3.2-2.3l1.1-2.7l2.3,0.3l0.2-0.6l-1.8-1v-0.5   h3.2l1.8-3.1l-1.3-1.9l-0.3-2.7l-1.5,0.2l-1.9,2.1l-0.6,2.6l-3.1-0.6l-1-1.8l1.8-1.9l2-1.8L776.2,573z"/>
    <path id="VA" data-info="<div>State: Virginia</div><div>Capital: Richmond</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M1002.9,369.2l-0.1-1.9l6.5-2.5l-0.8,3.2l-2.9,3.8l-0.4,4.6l0.5,3.4l-1.8,5l-2.2,1.9l-1.5-4.6   l0.4-5.4l1.6-4.2L1002.9,369.2z M1005.2,397.5L947,410.1l-37.4,5.3l-6.7-0.4l-2.6,1.9l-7.3,0.2l-8.4,1l-8.9,1l8.5-4.9l0-2.1   l1.5-2.1l10.6-11.5l3.9,4.5l3.8,1l2.5-1.1l2.2-1.3l2.5,1.3l3.9-1.4l1.9-4.6l2.6,0.5l2.9-2.1l1.8,0.5l2.8-3.7l0.3-2.1l-1-1.3l1-1.9   l5.3-12.3l0.6-5.7l1.2-0.5l2.2,2.4l3.9-0.3l1.9-7.6l2.8-0.6l1-2.7l2.6-2.3l1.3-2.3l1.5-3.4l0.1-5.1l9.8,3.8   c0.7,0.3,0.7-4.8,0.7-4.8l4.1,1.4l-0.5,2.6l8.2,2.9l1.3,1.8l-0.9,3.7l-1.3,1.3l-0.5,1.7l0.5,2.4l2,1.3l3.9,1.4l2.9,1l4.9,0.9   l2.2,2.1l3.2,0.4l0.9,1.2l-0.4,4.7l1.4,1.1l-0.5,1.9l1.2,0.8l-0.2,1.4l-2.7-0.1l0.1,1.6l2.3,1.5l0.1,1.4l1.8,1.8l0.5,2.5l-2.6,1.4   l1.6,1.5l5.8-1.7L1005.2,397.5z"/>
    <g id="DC">
        <path id="path58" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M975.8,353.8l-1.1-1.6l-1-0.8l1.1-1.6l2.2,1.5L975.8,353.8z"/>
        <circle id="circle60" data-info="<div>Washington DC</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.5" cx="975.3" cy="351.8" r="5"/>
    </g>
</g>
<path id="path67" fill="none" stroke="#A9A9A9" stroke-width="2" d="M385,593v55l36,45 M174,525h144l67,68h86l53,54v46"/>

</svg>
</a>

<div class="popup">
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">
  <div  id="divContentToPopup">
    <form class="jotform-form" action="https://submit.jotform.me/submit/73025839438463/" method="post" name="form_73025839438463" id="73025839438463" accept-charset="utf-8" novalidate="true">
    </form>
  <div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is the pop() defined?

Comment: I copied the code

Comment: path, circle it is the map class,and .jotform-form it is the form class

Answer (score 0):

You have to write some javascript which makes the form visible upon clicking.

`pop()` is the current function bound to the click event on the map. So it might look a bit like this.

```
function pop() {
    console.log("User clicked on map")
    $(".popup").css("display", "static"); 
}
```

You have to play around with the css the make this look good.
You can also use `$(".popup").addClass("popped");` and style popped for a good pop-up effect.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code and you will be able to open form on the click of anchor.

```
var pop = function() {
  window.open('https://form.jotform.com/73025839438463', 'blank', 'scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no, width=700, height=500');
}
```

Here is some [documentation](https://www.jotform.com/help/447-How-to-Open-Your-Form-in-a-Popup-Window). 
You can check out the [working demo](https://jsbin.com/pofehomipu/edit?html,js,output).